# php includes that include another php file

Tags: php, include, server-side-includes, nested-includes

I'm getting really muddled up now and my brain hurts! :( lol

Root:

- index.php

Includes:

- cat.php
- dog.php

index includes dog:  include("includes/dog.php");

dog includes cat: include("cat.php");

When I run index, for cat it says:

1. A link to the server could not be established
2. Access denied for user ...

However, if I run dog, I get no problems...

I'm guessing its the path, but i've tried ./includes/cat.php to no joy...

Answer (score 5):

This is because when you include a relative path, it's relative to the entry point (the first PHP file, called by the webserver).

In dog, do

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/cat.php'); // __FILE__ is always the name of the php file it's in
```

Comment: yup, Emma you are including file a/c dog.php but instead you should include a/c index.php. just think like dog.php is gonna paste in index.php and use your pathing a/c that

Comment: Thanks Bart.  Hopefully that will fix it.  I need to clean up some bits first...

Nik - I'm not sure I follow, sorry.  Do you mean that I should include dog and cat from index and then not worry about doing those includes?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where the script you are executing lies. When you execute `/index.php` the path of the script set to `/`, so all includes start from there. This means that you *can* find `/includes/dog.php`, but it's not possible to find `/cats.php`. Mind that, even if you are including `cats.php` from your `/includes/dog.php` script, this doesn't change the original execuption path.

When, on the other hand, you are executing `/includes/dog.php`, your path is set to `/includes/`, which is why PHP can also find `cats.php`.

Read Bart's comment on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve this is to set the include path of files, take a look at this.

http://ve2.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this nice thread.

I used bart's answer to solve this issue. But I still have one question here.

I was surprised that it worked in my mate's system even without using  `dirname(__FILE__)` so I did little research and compared both php.ini files. I noticed there is little difference at `include_path` parameter in php.ini.

In my php.ini it is set to Pear directory.  So I commented out just to test and to my wonder it worked. This is when I realized we need to include some folder which I dont know or comment it out so that it takes default value.